# Toggle the GPS to "North up"

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA V, is there any way to toggle the GPS screen to be in a fixed position so that North is always up? I like to know which direction I am going without having to pause to look at the map, or to look at the angles of the shadows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely on the mini-map, there is a small '**N**' which shows which direction the North is. It moves around all over the map border and is not always towards UP but, you can use it to align yourself towards North.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm sitting too far from my TV. I never noticed that. It's funny that such a big budget game wouldn't have the option to toggle this to North-up, but that works.